# 404 when trying to serve files from the filesystem

Tags: go

```
import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

I navigate to localhost:8080/ and get a 404 error. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What would you expect from a GET / ?

Comment: My Index.html in the static folder

Comment: What does `server.RegisterHandlers()` do? The code should work fine without it, given you have a folder named "static".

Comment: Sorry, removed the line. Still doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    server.RegisterHandlers()

    // Get the running directory.
    runningDirectory, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        // Handle the error.
        return err
    }

    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(runningDirectory + "/static"))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: Nice that it worked! Do you know why a full path might be required when normally a relative should be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

With the following structure:

```
main.go
static
  |- index.html
```

And with `main.go` containing:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

After running your solution with `go run main.go`, you should be able to go to `localhost:8080/` and end up with the content of `index.html`.

If it doesn't work, maybe the added error handling might help out. The code is correct.